# How can't my django admin got no css attached?

Tags: python, css, django

I have followed my first Django App video series on Youtube. I have created admin, but I am unable to load CSS:

[image]

What I want is this:

[image]

Comment: can you write down the full code?

Answer (score 0):

go incognito and try loadin it again if it loads that means its a cache problem you fix it by refreshing the page with  CTRL+F5 .

if you setup STATIC_ROOT and STATIC_URL in your setting.py you have to run python manage.py collectstatic